# Print preview is not displaying the right layout

Tags: html, css

I need to print my html so I lay out the way I want the print out to be. But when I click on the `print button` and get directed to the print preview, the layout are all messed up. Please see my code below:

**in html**

```
<div id="print-section" *ngIf="propertyLedger">
  <h2>SOSA | PMIS</h2>
  <hr>
  <table class="table borderless">
      <tr>
          <th class="col-md-2">Transaction Date</th>
          <td>{{dateToday | date}}</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">Collecting Agent</th>
      <td>{{propertyLedger.CollectinAgentName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">Unit Name</th>
      <td>{{propertyLedger.UnitName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">Payment Type</th>
      <td>{{propertyLedger.PaymentType}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">O.R. Number</th>
      <td>{{propertyLedger.ORNumber}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">Remarks</th>
      <td>{{propertyLedger.Remarks}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <h3>Details</h3>
  <hr>
</div>
    <button 

class="btn btn-primary" (click)="print()">Print</button>
```

**in the ts file**

```
print() {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Print tab</title>
            <style>
            //........Customized style.......
            </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
        </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

**in my layout**
[image]
as soon as I click the print =>

**in my print preview**
  [image]
It seems that the texts in the left part of the table goes to the center. Can you help me with this please. If you have a way to get my desired layout without any table that will be best! Thank you so much.

Comment: You can try by adding `text-align:left` css on all cell. Remember to give your css media to `all` or `print`.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. If you have a way to just use tabs or css that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read up. A default  in HTML has these properties.

```
th {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center
}
```

You have to change it to something like this:

```
th {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Moreover, if you are not using HTML5 you can also make the  tag something like this:

```html
<th align="left" class="col-md-2">Unit Name</th>
```

Comment: Thank you. This will definitely work. But I just added an inline style for each `<th>` and have it text-align: left. Do you have a way to make it like so without the use of table? say just using tabs or css?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 I am not too sure. I think the table is the only way to keep the text in an organized manner. I am a beginner coder by the way... ;D

Comment: Great! Maybe we can change ideas and techniques  someday.